# how to Change "source" of a user defined style Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am very new to .Net, C# and WP7 but working on same. I need to create an array of "buttons" ***from code behind(C#)***. Each button have a textblock and a picture but text of Textblock and source of picture will be diff. for rach button.So i had created a Style-style having a textblock and an Image. Now need to set text to TextBlock and imageSource to Image at the time creating the button. Please help me out with sample code as i am trying for this since last 3 days but can't find the solution or mya be missing with some basic technique.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="style" x:Key="UnChecked" TargetType="Button" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                        <Canvas x:Name="list" >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Site" **Text=""** TextWrapping="NoWrap" Canvas.Top="104" Width="114" Height="48" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Canvas.Left="16" />
                            <Image x:Name="Logo" Width="128" Height="104"  UseLayoutRounding="True" **Source=""** />                            
                        </Canvas>                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

//Code behind

Please help me out **OR** let me know if me doing some blunder

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, as usual ... one thing you could do, depending on your needs is. You create a class that contains your informations like

```
public class ButtonInfo
{
    public string Text{get;set;}
    public BitmapSource Image {get;set;}
    public ICommand Command{get;set;}
}
```

now, when you create your buttons

```
var btn = new Button();
vat info = new ButtonInfo();
info.Text ="Some caption";
// load an image
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg");
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
// set the image
info.Image = myBitmapImage;

// set the button info onto our button

btn.DataContext = info;
```

Now you need to modify you style a bit

```
<Canvas x:Name="list" >
  <TextBlock x:Name="Site" Text="{Binding Text}" />
  <Image x:Name="Logo" Width="128" Height="104" Source="{Binding Image}" />                            
</Canvas>
```

So what did we do here? We created an object holding the dynamic informations for our buttons into `ButtonInfo`, on creation of the Buttons we set these individual ButtonInfos onto the Buttons, now via DataBinding we got the Data out of the ButtonInfo into our Controls.
I added the Command property aswell because i think this would be the next thing you could stumple apon. Which can be fixed, adding

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
```

to your button style.

Well like i said, this is just one way to do it and imo not the best way. But it might be sufficient.

Also i need to add that i come from a WPF background and some things might be different in silverlight, but i guess these fundamental concepts are the same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now its working but only for Textbox not for Image.

Comment: Actually, Text for Tesblocks is changing at rutime but for Image it is not showing anything. If u have any idaea what sort of mistake it pls let me know

Comment: @Dheeraj does it work now? because if your problem is solved, please mark the answer that helped you as accepted answer.